# How to remove label of textfield?

Tags: flutter, dart

Would like to ask if it is possible to remove the label "Label" on top left of the text field in Flutter.

[image]

Comment: any update for this?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes it is fixed now based on your suggestion

Answer (score 37):

Yes, set the floatingLabelBehavior to never in InputDecoration. It worked for me.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
),
```

Comment: this answer should be mark as accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Yes, is it possible. Just remove the `hintText` and `labelText` in `InputDecoration`.

```
     decoration: InputDecoration(
         border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
           const Radius.circular(5.0),
      )),
      // hintText: Localization.of(context).accessLevel,
      // labelText: Localization.of(context).accessLevel,
   ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the floatingLabelBehaviour option as follows:

```
inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code removes the LabelText when you write anything in the TextField and shows LabelText when you do not write anything in the TextField.

```
    TextEditingController Controller = TextEditingController();
    
    bool  ForBool = true;
    
    TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (value.length <= 0) {
                setState(() {
                  ForBool = false;
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  ForBool = true;
                });
              }
              Controller.text = value;
              print(value);
              Controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                  TextPosition(offset: Controller.text.length));
            },
            controller: Controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: ForBool ? null : "Search...",
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply Remove the **labelText** property in the InputDecoration.

Comment: It does not work.
What we want is to use a labelText, but when we click to type, we hide it :)